# hadoop mapreduce job is not running

Tags: mapreduce, jobs

i have created a basic mapreduce program and created jar file out of it. when i am trying to run it from console like:

`[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop jar /home/cloudera/Desktop/csvjar.jar testpackage.Mapreduce /import/climate /output5`

Nothing is happening, no error or map reduce status. It just displays

`[cloudera@localhost ~]`

Mapreduce is the class where map, reduce and main function resides. Jar file kept on local machine and HDFS also. I have tried with both the paths. Nothing happened in both the conditions. Output5 folder does not exist in the hdfs.

Comment: You may post your source code to clarify the situation a little bit more

Comment: You definitely need to post your code for us to figure anything out.

Answer (score 0):

I also came through the same issue. In my code, I missed the closing braces while checking the arguments section in the driver code. I am attaching the part of the code with "}" for reference.

```
    if(otherArgs.length !=3){
         System.err.println("Number of argument passed is not 3");
         System.exit(1);
     }
```

I hope this would help you.